# How do I navigate backwards forwards when there's no physical or screen buttons?

Tags: safari, iphone

I went on a movie streaming site and a bunch of "popups" came up, like suddenly I was in the appstore or some completely different tab. The real tab I wanted to go to is probably somewhere opened too, but what do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably switched to the App Store app through a URI scheme. The web page will still be open in Safari. You can either switch back to Safari normally using the home screen or through multitasking.

Comment: how do i multi task?

Comment: @Blub Double-press the home button, swipe to the app if necessary and tap it to switch to it.